# Why do I get two different dictionaries, if I reverse the order of the zip lists

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, dictionary

I am a bit puzzled by the following code:

```
Python 2.7.13 (default, Jan 19 2017, 14:48:08)
[GCC 6.3.0 20170118] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> list_a = ['300', '300', '200', '150', '150', '120', '1']

>>> list_b = ['butter', 'sugar', 'yolks', 'flour', 'potato_starch', 'egg_whites', 'lemon_zest']

>>> c = dict(zip(list_b, list_a))

>>> print c
>>>{'butter': '300', 'lemon_zest': '1', 'flour': '150', 'egg_whites': '120', 'sugar': '300', 'yolks': '200', 'potato_starch': '150'}

>>> c = dict(zip(list_a, list_b))

>>> print c
>>>{'300': 'sugar', '200': 'yolks', '1': 'lemon_zest', '120': 'egg_whites', '150': 'potato_starch'}
```

Why by reversing the lists, the dictionary 'c' loses two pairs 'ingredient: quantity'?
I noticed that up to 6 pairs is all right.
I apologize for the incomplete explanation, but I do not know how to explain this to me that is an abnormality.
Thanks to who will want to help me understand.

Comment: Dictionary keys have to be unique. If you make keys from `list_a` it contains duplicates, so you overwrite any existing data stored against that key.

Answer (score 5):

Reversing the order of the arguments means the previous dictionary values will now take precedence as keys.

More so, the previous dictionary had duplicate values (e.g. 300). However, once you swap the order of the arguments and they become keys, only one of those values makes it as a key into the new dict; dictionaries do not allow duplicate keys.

Comment: Thanks now I understand

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple items with the same number, thus overwriting the value for that specific key.

`{"a":300, "b":300}` would become `{300:"a", 300:"b"}`. Since keys must be unique, the `dict` gets created by first assigning "a" to the key 300, which then gets immediately overwritten by "b".

Comment: @tobias_k Exactly: {"a":300, "b":300} would become {300:"a", 300:"b"}, which is invalid, since keys must be unique.

Comment: Thanks now I understand

Comment: @EricDuminil: You're right, wrong choice of words. Edited and hopefully clarified my point. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your data structure, you might be interested in a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

list_a = ['200', '300', '300', '200', '150', '150', '120', '1']
list_b = ['butter', 'butter', 'sugar', 'yolks', 'flour', 'potato_starch', 'egg_whites', 'lemon_zest']

ingredients = Counter()

for ingredient, quantity in zip(list_b, list_a):
    ingredients[ingredient] += int(quantity)

print(ingredients)
# Counter({'butter': 500, 'sugar': 300, 'yolks': 200, 'flour': 150, 'potato_starch': 150, 'egg_whites': 120, 'lemon_zest': 1})
```

For each ingredient, it will sum the quantities instead of overwriting the values when a key appears more than once (e.g. with `'butter'` : 200 and 300).

Comment: Ok thanks, i should not have double ingredients but your integration can be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
d = dict(zip(list_a, list_b))
    if len(d) != len(list_a):
        d = dict(zip(list_b, list_a))
```

Check the length of the dictionary and if it is not equal to the length of one of the two lists, invert the order of 'zip'